# formated windows without uninstalling ubuntu

Tags: format, software-uninstall

I have formatted my laptop before I uninstalled Ubuntu from it and now it has it as a "choice" in my boot options but I can't boot it because the drive was formatted. If I install it, it duplicates Ubuntu. is there a way to remove that duplicated choice?

Answer (score 1):

updating the grub menu would solve the problem

> sudo update-grub

Answer (score 0):

You need to install grub customiser:

`sudo apt-get install grub-customiser`

With it you can delete individual entries, and even change the order.